# Receive notifications of a pending drag-and-drop operation over my window in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I have an MFC dialog window with controls in it that support drag-and-drop feature. Those controls are registered to receive drag-and-drops, and that part works fine.

My question is about my main MFC dialog window. Is it possible to receive notifications in it when drag-and-dropped "object" is being dragged over that window, and at what coordinate is it over my window?

PS. I need this functionality to "unfurl" certain controls in the main window while drag-and-drop is in progress so that the user could then drop "objects" into them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [COleDropTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w4z9dwh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class. Basically, you create a member variable inside your main window, then call COleDropTarget::Register method to register the window. Then you need to implement OnDragEnter(), OnDragOver(), OnDragLeave(), OnDrop() in your window.

See this [nice codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/840/How-to-Implement-Drag-and-Drop-Between-Your-Progra) article as an example (skip the section about DragAcceptFiles, I have a feeling that you do need to support files, otherwise, it is even easier.)